# Is ther an Azure WebJob Configuration to control logging?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I am experimenting with WebJobs. I created a new WebJob project in Visual Studio 2015. Here is the code:

```
public class Program
{
    // Please set the following connection strings in app.config for this WebJob to run:
    // AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage
    public static void Main()
    {
        JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
        config.Tracing.ConsoleLevel = TraceLevel.Info;

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsEnv", "Development");

        if(config.IsDevelopment)
        {
            config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
        }

        config.UseTimers();

        JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
}

public class Functions
{
    public static void GetMarketData([TimerTrigger("00:00:01")] TimerInfo timer, TextWriter log)
    {
        //log.WriteLine($"Market data retrieved at {DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd HH:mm:ss")}");
    }
}
```

As you can see I am using the Timers extension so that the function is called every one second.

When I run this locally (and assuming on Azure too) even though I have commented out the log.WriteLine in the function, there are logs created on the storage account I have created. There are output-logs with files showing empty text and there are host logs with information about the function.

Imagine that there is one of each log every second. How can I stop those logs from being written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to set the dashboard connection string to null as shown in the following example to disable logging.

```
var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

config.DashboardConnectionString = "";
config.UseTimers();

var host = new JobHost(config);
host.RunAndBlock();
```

Comment: Thank you. This stopped the app-logs from being written. If I want to add logging where I see fit, I assume I will have to manually write to the blobs.